# HTTP doesn't work in Android emulator

Tags: android, http

I tried multiple HTTP classes (`HttpURLConnection`, `HTTPClient` and others) but they don't work in emulator. Then I decided to test that on my phone and it worked well!

So how can I fix this strange behaviour of Android emulator that HTTP classes don't work (while browser can work)? They crash an application at all.

Here is my code:

```
public static SimpleXML getResponse(String action, Map<String, String> params) {
     // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(action);

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(params.size());
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> heh : params.entrySet())
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(heh.getKey(), heh.getValue()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return SimpleXML.loadXml(response.getEntity().getContent());       

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }   
}
```

LogCat log:

```
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at net.ekvium.air.API.getResponse(API.java:98)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at net.ekvium.air.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-30 22:07:28.972: E/AndroidRuntime(682):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show your code. Also explain what "...they don't work..." means.

Comment: I updated the post. They don't work because they just crash my application.

Comment: um... sorry... what log?

Comment: If your app crashes the LogCat should show the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: I added LogCat log to the post.

Comment: Where is `getResponse()` called from?  Is it called from some method that's run on the UI thread (such as `onCreate()`, or in a button click handler)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you look at [this Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), it explains

**NetworkOnMainThreadException:**

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

So, depending on OS version, there may be enforcement (exception throwing) of the policy that you not make network requests on the UI thread.  This could explain why your code works on a device, and not on an emulator (if they have different Android versions).

You *could* change the `ThreadPolicy`.  But as an alternative, I'd suggest you look again at the statement in the Android docs.  They **heavily** discourage performing network operations on the main thread, and I'd certainly agree with them.

So, rather than changing the policy to *make it legal*, you might consider changing your code, so that your `getResponse()` method is not called on the UI thread.

Typically, you would use [AsyncTask to do the work in the background](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Nice. That's probably even better than that solution with permitAll(). But I have a question. I am making authorization. How should I do it with AsyncTask? I send login and password using POST.

Comment: @Uhehesh, Just wanted to give you another option.  As usual, there's more than one way to solve a problem :)

Comment: @Uhehesh, I was just saying that you **can** solve the problem by changing `ThreadPolicy`, as the other answer describes.  **Or**, you could change your code to not call `getResponse()` on the main/UI thread.  Both will stop your program from crashing with that exception.  But, if you just change `ThreadPolicy`, your UI will be frozen while the network request is being performed.  If that takes more than a fraction of a second, the user may not be happy.

Comment: yes, I don't like that and I want another way to do that. Not in the main thread.

Comment: @Uhehesh, I agree.  Look at the `AsyncTask` link in my answer above.

Comment: that's OK. But my code crashes. Maybe because I call Toast inside AsyncTask? So I shouldn't call Toast there but to move it to main thread, yes?

Comment: @Uhehesh, I can't tell without seeing how you use `Toast`.  You should probably just start a new question, posting the code that uses `AsyncTask` and `Toast`, and tell us what's not working.  That's really a different problem than why you got the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: okay, really. Thank you for answer though! No more discussion in comments.

Answer (score 15):

This happens because you try to perform network activity on the main thread.

I had the same issue, It worked for a while, then after a few weeks of developing, it stopped working.

The solution I found was to add these lines to the

```
onCreate()
```

Method:

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Hope this works for you too

**EDIT**

Due to increasing number of upvotes, I wish to add something.
This will remove the `NetworkingOnMainThreadException`, **HOWEVER, it is by far not a recommended way.**

This exception is there for a reason. Network activity can take time, performing networking on the main thread, which is the same thread that responsible for updating the UI, would freeze the thread until the networking is done (this is what happens on every thread, but when it's performed on a dedicated thread, it's ok). In Android, if the UI-thread isn't active for 5 seconds, it will show the `Application is not responsive, Do you want to close it?` dialog.

This is what the exception has come to prevent. Setting the policy, like I suggested, while removes the exception, is the wrong way of doing things.
Any networking actions should be done on a separate thread, either by using `AsyncTask` or by creating new `Thread` manually. `AsyncTask` are a very easy and straight-forward way of implementing this, and this is what I recommend.

Please take this edit into consideration when using my answer.

Cheers

Comment: Any downvoters, your opinions counts more than just a downvote. if you think this solution isn't good, say it. don't just mark it. this way both the one who asked and me, could improve...

Because when I found this answer, it had like 15 up votes...

Comment: Brilliant. It helped me! I would vote up but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer (good to know how to change policies!), and I agree that down voters should comment, but the downside of doing this is that it's really subverting Android's recommendation to not perform network requests on the UI thread.  Normally (but not always, of course), that's good advice.

Answer (score 0):

You disable the strict mode using following code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

**This is not recommended:** use the `AsyncTask` interface.

[Link of AsyncTask](http://www.javaexperience.com/android-create-non-blocking-user-interface/)

[Link of another reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)