# java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message soap

Tags: java, android, soap, httptransportse

that my source code,

```
private static final String URL = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso";
private static final String NAME_SPACE = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu";
private static final String METHODE_NAME = "TopGoalScorers";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = NAME_SPACE + "/" + METHODE_NAME;


SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAME_SPACE, METHODE_NAME);

    request.addProperty("iTopN", 10);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


    SoapObject soapObject = null;
    try {
        transporte.call("http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso/TopGoalScorers", envelope);

        soapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Soap", e.getMessage());
    }
```

and i give this error:

```
> 01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.serviosweb/com.android.serviosweb.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at com.android.serviosweb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-29 10:44:17.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10704):    ... 11 more
```

any one help me please

Answer (score 3):

In the catch statement use:

```
String errorMessage = (ex.getMessage()==null)?"Message is empty":ex.getMessage();
Log.e("Message:",errorMessage );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the catch, use:

```
String err = (ex.getMessage()==null)?"SD Card failed":ex.getMessage();
Log.e("sdcard-err2:",err);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is quite simple. There is an Exception thrown inside your try Block. The Catch-Block now tries to handle these Exception, by printing the Exception message to your Log. Unlikely the message you want to print is not set, and your Logger(sys.out.print) is not capable of printing nothing (a null value).

As long as you want to print the StackTrace instead like Mohamed_AbdAllah suggested. You need to get the StackTrace as String Guava and Apache Commons have Methods for these purpose. A simple build your own way would be:

```
StackTraceElement[] stack = e.getStackTrace();
StringTrace = "";
for(StackTraceElement line : stack)
{
   Trace += line.toString();
}

    Log.e("Soap",Trace);
```

Comment: thank you, the result is: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@41501db8

Comment: I Updated my original answer.

Comment: thank you that is the error is so big for post it here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/amhi1zn0korxu6a/error.txt

Comment: Now, you are facing a different Error, your real Error. I'm not in Android but i think this is maybe the answer [Link to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277734/http-doesnt-work-in-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :(For example)

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo username = new PropertyInfo();
        username.setName("username");
        username.setValue("google");
        username.setType(String.class);
        username.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
        request.addProperty(username);
```