# Unable to connect with internet

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to connect with internet with this code:

```
  DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.100/webnet/xyz.php");
  String result = null;
  InputStream is = null;
  StringBuilder sb = null;
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I registered Internet permission on manifest file

I got this error:

> System.err    android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)

I tests this app with API level 8

Comment: which os version have you tested?

Comment: I have to ask, do you not have a search engine accessible from your location?, possible duplicate of [HTTP doesn't work in Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277734/http-doesnt-work-in-android-emulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this before executing this block of code.  may works in some cases:

```
try {
                Class strictModeClass=Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode");
                Class strictModeThreadPolicyClass=Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy");
                Object laxPolicy = strictModeThreadPolicyClass.getField("LAX").get(null);
                Method method_setThreadPolicy = strictModeClass.getMethod("setThreadPolicy",strictModeThreadPolicyClass );
                method_setThreadPolicy.invoke(null,laxPolicy);
            }
        catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

And Try this before asking questions here: "google.com" # agree with kevinDTimm

Anyway you SHOULD NOT call network on UI threads.

Comment: I'd say this is the worst solution for this problem, nevermind it was accepted. Don't do that!

Answer (score 4):

You can not run long running task on main thread. please move your network related task in background.

Refer this : [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: @juned - please don't reward the lazy, this question has been answered numerous times.

Answer (score 2):

Since Android 3.0, you'll see this error when you're trying to make network requests from the main thread. Move this code to a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

You check first which ip-address is the on (IPV4/IPV6)

Comment: the address is working on my browser but not working in android